# My post permalinks are redirecting to the post archive page for some reason?

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I updated my permalink structure so that my posts were prefixed with `/stories/`.

So in `Settings -> Permalinks`: `Custom structure: /stories/%postname%/`.

My post permalinks updated correctly in the backend, yet when I click on one to view something like `https://example.com/stories/22222` it simply redirects me to `https://example.com/stories`.

I don't know if it's worth noting that all of my post titles (names) are numeric. So my post title would be 22222.

I don't get a 404 or anything like that, it just redirects to the archive page. Yet, when I type in something like `https://example.com/stories/foo` I will get the appropriate 404 page.

Does it have something to do with my numeric post titles?

Comment: "redirects to the archive page" - although this might not be the case, did you set your Category/Tag archive base to `stories` (see at the bottom of the Permalink Settings page)? Or do you have a Page (post type `page`) with the slug `stories`? How about custom post type where the archive (`has_archive`) is set to `stories` - got any?

Comment: These were good checks but no, none of these. Category/Tag base is empty, no pages named stories, and no custom post type. When I go to `https://example.com/stories/775`, for example, I do see a 301 redirect in chrome dev tools. I think it has something to do with numeric post titles. It's a long thread but I just found this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305. When I change the post title to "Story 775" `https://example.com/stories/story-775` works.

Comment: Yes, it could be a conflict with the post pagination (e.g. `example.com/post-slug/3`) for Posts/Pages/CPT that are split into multiple pages, but try switching to a default theme and/or deactivate all plugins, then see if the problem persists.

Comment: Woops. I do have a page called Stories. It's set to the "Posts Page" in Homepage settings. So the stories page is the archive. Would this cause an issue?

Comment: Yes, very likely because of what I said in my previous comment - post pagination conflict. So you have to change the Page slug or use another slug for the permalink structure.

Comment: That worked! I changed the slug for the Stories page to `all-stories`. With pagination, the URLs looked like `https://example.com/stories/page/2`.

Comment: Yes, that's the pagination for archive-based pages like the "blog" page which displays multiple posts. But the one I was referring to is singular post pagination (see the [Page Break Block](https://wordpress.org/support/article/page-break-block/) in the Gutenberg/block editor).